# WPF panel that behaves like iphone home screen

Tags: c#, wpf

Before jumping to coding, just wanted to know if there's somewhere out there.
I'm looking for a WPF panel that behaves like iphone home screen (I need the following features)

- Reorder items by drag & drop
- Dragging 1 item another item joins them both into a folder
- Clicking on a folder opens a popup with all items
- Dragging an item into a folder moves it to the folder
- Similar animations as in iphone would be nice

Thanks in advance, Benny

Comment: I don't know a control like this but perhaps you can finde something if your search for the hub and spoke ui pattern

Comment: Did you try searching google??

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244134/WPFSpark-3-of-n-FluidWrapPanel something like this maybe? Search CodeProject for more.

Comment: @Blachshma, I did try but did not find the whole 9 yards, just partial solutions.

Comment: @dutzu, thanks I might use it, but it doesn't have folders